# Desktop folders still open in Nautilus after making Thunar the default file manager

Tags: gnome, nautilus, thunar

I followed this guide to make Thunar my default file manager: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager

However, double-clicking Desktop folders open them in Nautilus. I guess that's because Nautilus is still managing my Desktop (which is something Thunar cannot do)?

How do I make Desktop folders open in Thunar?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this previously with nemo, but at that time ( ~3 years ago ) there was not an equivalent to the following for Thunar.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

Separately, you can look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager#Script_to_change_Thunar_to_be_the_default_file_manager if it still applies.